# A function is 0 if is almost bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I am having problems with this excercise, if $f$ is analytic in $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ and:

$$|f(\cos(z))| \leq m|z|^n$$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z \in D$. Then show that  $f \equiv 0$.

Please some hint could be very useful.

Comment: By Liouvilles theorem $f(cos(z))$ is a polynomial of at most degree $n$. Now use the periodicity of $cos$ to show that $f\circ cos$ has infinitely many roots.

Comment: @MaikPickl but Liouville dont need that f is analytic in the entire complex plane?

Comment: Hmm, I just saw you’re function is not defined on the whole of the complex plane. Are you sure about that? What is $D$ in your exercise?

Comment: Yes.. $D$ can be any domain.

Comment: A counterexample is usefull to but I dont have any intuition on this

Comment: Well for arbitrary domains it’s certainly not true. You can define the inverse of $cos$ on certain domains (to be found on Wikipedia for example). Now let $f$ equal $arccos$ on such a domain and you have your counterexample.

Comment: @J.Rodriguez If $D$ is any domain containing the point $1$ then by Minimum Modulus Theorem, $f$ would be identically $0$. But for arbitrary domain I've doubt about the question !!

Answer (score 1):

As Maik Pickl said in the comments: let $D=\{\sigma+it: \sigma>1\}$ (because [the branch points are at $\pm 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Extension_to_complex_plane)) and $f$ be any branch of $\arccos(z)$ on $D$. Then $f$ is clearly nonzero, but $|f(\cos(z))|=|z|\leq m|z|^n$, not just for some choice of $m$ and $n$ but in fact for *every* choice of $m,n\in\Bbb N$!

Comment: This answer exists to remove this question from the Unanswered list. Please upvote or choose as Best Answer to complete the process.